# C- Structures and Unions

Tags: c, structure, unions

C standard states that only the members of a union are stored at the *same* address and ,because of which, we can access only one member at a time.Since the compiler overlays storage
for the members of a union, changing one member alters any value previously stored in any of the other members.So if we try to access the value of a member stored previously, the value will be meaningless or undefined.Now here is my question:-

```
struct catalog_item
{
   int stock_number;
   double price;
   int item_type;
   union
     {
       struct
          {
            char title[TITLE_LEN+1];
            char author[AUTHOR_LEN+1];
            int num_pages;
          } book;
       struct
          {
            char design[DESIGN_LEN+1];
          } mug;
       struct
          {
            char design[DESIGN_LEN+1];
            int colors;
            int sizes;
          } shirt;
     } item;
} c;
```

Now if the following is done

```
strcpy(c.item.mug.design, "Butterfly");
```

then both of the following have the same value

```
printf("%s",c.item.mug.design);          //1
```

and

```
printf("%s",c.item.shirt.design);        //2
```

Why is the result of "2" is not undefined or meaningless?

Comment: What makes you think that #2 is well defined? Just because it happens to work when you tried, doesn't mean it's defined to do that.

Comment: @Barmar You are correct that there is no assurance in the language that states these necessarily will line up as they have.  It's dependent on the compiler implementation of struct definitions.

Comment: printf  prints whats in memory, witout any particular check of the origin (it can't).  And  mug.design and shirt.design refer to the same space .

Comment: also note that a c compiler never reorders data for alignment constraints. So you are sure to have a string at the start of the struct. Thus shirt.design is perfectly defined and can be accessed via mug.design (but not recommended to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not undefined behavior but it is implementation defined behavior, if we look at the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) *footnote 82* says:

> If the **member used to access the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object**, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type punning"). **This might be a trap representation.**

In practice this is supported in `C` and you should read the specific compilers documentation. For example if you examine the *Implementation-defined behavior* section for [Structures, unions, enumerations, and bit-fields](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit_002dfields-implementation.html#Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit_002dfields-implementation) in the `gcc` manual it points to [here for Type-punning](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Type_002dpunning.html#Type_002dpunning) and we can see under the *-fstrict-aliasing* section is says:

> The practice of reading from a different union member than the one most recently written to (called “type-punning”) is common. Even with -fstrict-aliasing, type-punning is allowed, provided the memory is accessed through the union type.

but there are caveats and you should read up on [strict aliasing](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) to understand all the details, [this article](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/) is gentler introduction.

For completeness section `3.4.1` defines *implementation-defined behavior* as:

> unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made

and the standard annex `J.1`  *Unspecified behavior* which lists the unspecified behavior covered by the standard includes this line:

> The value of a union member other than the last one stored into (6.2.6.1).

Comment: Since both `mug` and `shirt` begin with a field of type `char [DESIGN_LEN+1]`, shouldn't that be sufficient to guarantee that after the field is written using `mug.design` or `shirt.design`, it may be read using either of those members?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you need to think about data storage in C differently.  In essence, a union in C says that it can hold any of the items in it (enough memory is allocated for any type included), but that a single instance will only hold 1.  When you access a field, such as an integer, you're looking at the place in memory and treating the bits (0s and 1s) in memory there as an integer.  Strings are written as an array of characters.  You can look at any place in memory as a number and there will be one (constructed of whatever happen to be there before).  Now what you are seeing is that treating this union as either of two possible structures both contain the string.  This is because the location of the string is in the same place in either struct (at the beginning, offset 0), so with either you're resolving to the same location in memory.

Note that this is not guaranteed to line up this way, but only happens to line up because of your compilers interpretation of the structures.

Answer (score 0):

Your three structs in the union use the same memory area. The "design" field in two of those structs happen to fall in the same memory location. Thus, writing one also writes the other, the actual address is the same.